# Magento 2 checkout page add class to shipping method on click event

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, knockoutjs, magento2.3.0

I want to add **"active"** class on shipping method selection.
Means If I change shipping method then **"active"** class automatically added to newly selected shipping method and removed from the old selection.

Please see attached image.
[image]

I want to use knockout js and I am new to knockout js. Please help me.

Regards

Hiren Shah

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your custom js or phtml file:

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
   $(document).on("click", '{RdioButtonClassOrId}', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```